# "UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE" when my TFS build with "Prepare Analysis Configuration" task

Tags: maven, azure-devops, sonarqube

i facing the issue of UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE, when my TFS wanted to do builds with the task of Prepare analysis on SonarQube. For information ,my sonarQube, TFS and build agent is on diff server.

i did some research it might be because of my sonarQube server's cert issues.
If it cert issue...how could i solve it? i need to solve at TFS server or my build agent server? any article for me on solution?

if not....could tell me what the issue and guide me how to solve it?

Thanks you.

[The image of my TFS error pop out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzyxa.png)

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/getting-unable-to-verify-leaf-signature-error-in-vsts-prepare-task/448) support question?

Comment: somekind of....but mine not node.js